# How to compare Two GUID values (one from database and one hand-coded in "if" statement) in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've hand-coded value in table dbo.Integrations where one of the column, IntegrationId="907BC4CF-4DC0-41FB-8EA4-87FE73A5BAE3". I am trying to compare Guid value in order to return a function.

But I get this error:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' mcniDbC was null.

My code is:

```
/****************************************************************************************************************
 * File Name  : IntegrationsProcessor.cs
 * Description : This class is used for doing all Integration related database operation.
 * Created By : Anirudh Singh Rawat
 * Created Date : 6 April 2016
 ****************************************************************************************************************/

#region Namespace

using DBModel;
using MCNIDev.DBAccess;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity.Validation;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Utilities;

#endregion

namespace MCNIDev.Processor.Services
{
    public class IntegrationsProcessor
    {

        #region Private Member

        private MCNIDbContext mcniDbC;

        #endregion

        #region Public Methods

        /// <summary>
        /// This method is used for getting the existing 
        /// data from Integrations table.
        /// </summary>

        public Integration GetIntegrationRow()
        {
            
            return mcniDbC.Integration.FirstOrDefault(e => e.IntegrationId == Guid.Parse("907BC4CF-4DC0-41FB-8EA4-87FE73A5BAE3"));
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

This is the line of code causing the error:

```
return mcniDbC.Integration.FirstOrDefault(e => e.IntegrationId == Guid.Parse("907BC4CF-4DC0-41FB-8EA4-87FE73A5BAE3"));
```

Please not I am using this class to perform action on database by loosely coupling it with `DbContext` file `MCNIDbContext` in this case - and controller.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: You declare `mcniDbC` variable but not yet assign value (DbContext) to it.

Comment: I've already done that in another class and named it as "MCNIDbContext".

Comment: @AnirudhRawat when you create an instance of ```IntegrationsProcessor``` and you want to call ```GetIntegrationRow``` you need also an instance of ```MCNIDbContext```. Otherwise you will get a null reference exception as you already pointed out. By default, since  ```mcniDbC``` is a reference type and you don't initialize it anywhere during the creation of an instance of ```IntegrationsProcessor```, it's value would be null. That is needed is to supply an instance of ```MCNIDbContext``` to ```IntegrationsProcessor```. Define an constructor for ```IntegrationsProcessor``` that has one parameter

Comment: @AnirudhRawat ...this parameter would be of type ```MCNIDbContext```. Then set the supplied instance during constructor call to ```mcniDbC```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### ISSUE

You are getting NullReferenceException as you haven't assigned value to `mcniDbC`.

```
private MCNIDbContext mcniDbC;
```

You declare it but you not assign, hence by default it is `null`.

---

### SOLUTION: [Constructor Injection](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/85ed7a/dependency-injection-in-C-Sharp/)

You can create a constructor to assign the `mcniDbC`.

```
namespace MCNIDev.Processor.Services
{
    public class IntegrationsProcessor
    {

        #region Private Member

        private MCNIDbContext mcniDbC;

        #endregion

        public IntegrationsProcessor(MCNIDbContext context)
        {
            mcniDbC = context;
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

Next, in your main program, you instantiate `IntegrationsProcessor` as below:

```
var integrationProcessor = new IntegrationsProcessor(new MCNIDbContext());
```

This method is known as Constructor Injection which is one of the Dependency Injection methods.

Comment: Thank you for your help! It just worked fine. I will keep this in mind for the future.